# input slider in react

Tags: reactjs, slider

[image]

I have to create a slider as values are male, female and other based on slider on left, middle and right and highlight the value based on slider value. Help me as I am not getting any help from internet. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set a range in your slider from 0 - 100,  if the current value is between 1 - 33 you set to male, 34 - 66 female, 67-100 other

Comment: @Rodrigo how to highlight those boxes like female box appears larger in image. Any library in react for slider?

Comment: That`s a CSS trick, you need to do a condition with the slider value to the height and weight of the square, the same goes for fontStyle.